# Spring boot cache a field

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I have a spring boot application and i need to store a map in cache. This map can be updated by calling to REST API.

Can i declare a service field and use it with cache?

**pom:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**controller:**

```
@PostMapping("updateMap")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity uploadMap(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> data) {
    mapService.updateMap(data);   
    return ResponseEntity.ok();
}
```

**service**

```
// Is it possible to annotate it with @Cachable?    
private Map<String, Object> cachedMap;     



 public void updateMap(Map<String, Object> data) {
       //update cachedMap by data
    }

public Object getFromMap(String key) {
       //get object from map by key
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cacheable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) is an annotation targeted to methods, interfaces and classes. It is not targeted to fields as you intend to use it.

In your service you can create a `getMap` method and add the `@Cacheable` annotation to it. So everytime this method gets called (**outside of the service** due to Spring proxy, and apart from the first time that the map does not exist into cache) the map object returned will be the cached one.

```
@Cacheable("map")
public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
    // initialize your Map
    cachedMap = new HashMap<>();
    cachedMap.put("somekey", "aString");
    return cachedMap;
}
```

And if you want the cache to be updated each time you "update" the map as you do in your controller, then change your `public void updateMap(Map<String, Object> data)`:

```
@CachePut(value = "map")
public Map<String, Object> updateMap(Map<String, Object> data) {
    cachedMap.putAll(data);
    return cachedMap;
}
```

`@CachePut` will run the method's code anyway and add the returning result into cache.